# Extract rows based on max date for each id if another row value is duplicate in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove rows if `completion_dt` is duplicate for each `id`, keeping the row with max date from the `maturity_dt` column.

```
id  Maturity_dt     score   completion_dt
1   2020-12-31      12      2022-06-24
2   2020-12-31      8       2022-03-30
2   2019-12-31      0       2022-03-30
2   2018-12-31      0       2021-08-24
3   2022-12-31      15      2022-05-31
2   2021-12-31      12      2022-05-31
```

Desire Output:

```
id  Maturity_dt     score   completion_dt
1   2020-12-31      12      2022-06-24
2   2020-12-31      8       2022-03-30
2   2018-12-31      0       2021-08-24
3   2022-12-31      15      2022-05-31
2   2021-12-31      12      2022-05-31
```

I tried the following code but it's not working as expected.

```
df = df.sort_values('Maturity_dt').drop_duplicates(subset=['completion_dt', 'id'], keep='last')
```

Comment: You just have the order mixed up. do: `df.sort_values('Maturity_dt').drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'completion_dt'], keep='last')`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(['id', 'completion_dt'])['Maturity_dt'].idxmax()]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id Maturity_dt  score completion_dt
0   1  2020-12-31     12    2022-06-24
3   2  2018-12-31      0    2021-08-24
1   2  2020-12-31      8    2022-03-30
5   2  2021-12-31     12    2022-05-31
4   3  2022-12-31     15    2022-05-31
```